# Linear regression with different samples of data: addressing compatibility and parameter estimation

Tags: regression, fitting, paired-comparisons, linear, model-comparison

I have two samples of data (call 'em black and red), spread like in figure.
I ran a linear regression over both samples.
I understand that they cannot come from the same joint pdf f(x,y), and that a statistical test testing the distribution equality would fail. Given that  I would like to know:

- **In what sense I can consider the two samples "compatible"**: I think I can consider somehow the reds compatible with the blacks if the red outcomes are contained in the black's prediction intervals. Any theoretical reference to this?
- The two linear regressions (done separately over the blacks and the reds) yield beta coefficients statistically incompatible. Anyway I feel that would **make sense to run a linear regression over the blacks** (which are much more spread over x axis) **and to use its estimated coefficients to predict also the reds**. Is this justified somehow?

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Because "compatible" is vague and has no generally accepted statistical meaning, could you expand on what *you* mean by your uses of this word?

Comment: Why not estimate a single model with a dummy (0,1) variable indicating data type -- red vs black? This would be a direct test for any differences as well as evidence for using black to predict red.

Comment: @DJohnson Although that's reasonable advice generally, the scatterplot provides strong evidence for why it's not necessarily a good idea here: the distributions of the red errors have smaller variances than those of the black errors and there is some evidence of nonlinearity in the red points. Moreover, this question initially is phrased in terms of characterizing the joint distribution, raising an issue of whether regression is even an appropriate analytical method for that purpose.

Comment: I am open to suggestion about "compatible" meaning in this context. I suppose I might consider the reds compatible with the blacks if they are somehow contained into the black linear model prediction intervals.